# Distribution of a random vector

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis

I am trying to solve the next exercise but I don´t know how to solve this.

> Let $F$ be the multivariate distribution function of a random vector
>   $X\in\mathbb{R}^p$ and let $F_i$ be the univariate distribution of its
>   $i^\text{th}$ component $X_i$.
>
> For $0<u<1$ let $$F_i^{-1}(u)=\min\{r\in\mathbb{R}:F_i(r)\geq u\}.$$
>   Determine the distribution function $F$ of the random vector
>   $X:=(F_i^{-1}(U))_{i=1}^p$ with $U\sim \operatorname{Uniform}[0,1].$
>   In case of $p=2$ determine the distribution function of
>   $X:=(F_1^{-1}(U),F_2^{-1}(1-U))^T$.

Well, I have been trying the next:

First I know by definition of Distribution function that:

$$P(X\leq x)=P(X_1\leq x_1,...,X_p\leq x_p)$$
Replacing it with the definition of $X$ given:
$$=P(F_1^{-1}(U)\leq x_1,F_2^{-1}(U)\leq x_2,....,F_p^{-1}(U)\leq x_p).$$
Now I think in put something like that, since  $F_i^{-1}(U)\leq x_i$, this is equivalent to $U\leq F_i(x_i)$ I will have the expression for something like that:
$$P(U\leq F_1(x_1),..,U \leq F_p(x_p).)$$

But from here I don´t know how to proceed, maybe is something basic but really I don´t understand this kind of exercises.

Comment: You would make some progress by fixing the (many) typographical errors in this account.  In particular, why are you referencing just a single variable $U$ rather than a collection of such variables?

Comment: Could you explain me more about that? I have used the vector $U$ because of the definition is given for $X:=(F_i^{-1}(U))_{i=1}^p$, in this case it means that $X=(F_1^{-1}(U),...,F_p^{-1}(U))$. Some times I have problems with this, I need to find $P(X\leq x)=P(F_i^{-1}(U)\leq x)$, in this case how to note what is $x$? is a vector or only a number?

Comment: The initial probability you write, $\Pr(X_1\le x_1,\ldots,X_p\le x_p)$, is *multivariate*: it is a probability for the random *vector* $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_p)$. The final probability, $\Pr(U\le F_1(x_1),\ldots, U\le F_p(x_p))$ is purely *univariate*: it depends only on a random *number* $U$.  You would do well to consider the case $p=2$, for which you can easily depict this first event in a Cartesian plane (and the second event on a line representing values of $U$).

Comment: Could you explain me it in more detail please, I am not sure in how to depict this situation in the cartesian plane. With your last suggestion it means that the distribution of $X$ depends only of $U$?

Comment: I have the next solution for $p=2$:  $P(X\leq x)=P(X_1\leq x_1,X_2\leq x_2)$ using again the argument given by the exercise: $$P(X\leq x)=P(F_1^{-1}(U),F_2^{-1}(1-U))=P(U\leq F_1(x_1),U\geq1-F_2(x_2))$$ but, what can I say after this step?

Comment: Since $U$ is uniform, probabilities of events $a\le U \le b$ are easy to write down. In your comment, let $a=1-F_2(x_2)$ and $b=F_1(x_1)$.